# Episerver Scheduled Job fails (scheduler service)

Tags: episerver

Our scheduled jobs started failing since yesterday with the following error message:

> CustomUpdate.Execute - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference
>   not set to an instance of an object. at
>   System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(String username) at
>   EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.CreatePrincipal(String username)

The scheduled job uses anonymous execution and logs in programmatically using the following call:

```
if (PrincipalInfo.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name == string.Empty)
{
     PrincipalInfo.CurrentPrincipal = PrincipalInfo.CreatePrincipal(ApplicationSettings.ScheduledJobUsername);
}
```

I have put in some more logging around PrincipalInfo.CreatePrincipal call which is in Episerver.Security and noticed that PrincipalInfo.CreatePrincipal calls System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser(username) and Roles.GetRolesForUser(username) returns an empty string array.
There were no changes code wise or on the server (updates, etc).
I checked that the user name used to run the task is in the database and has roles associated with it.
I checked that applicationname is set up correctly and is associated with the user
If i run the job manually using the same user it executes with no issues (i know there is a difference between running the  job manually and using the scheduler)
I also tried creating a new user, that didn’t work either.
Has anyone come across the same or similar issue? Any thoughts how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Just in case - can you ensure (via logging) that `ApplicationSettings.ScheduledJobUsername` contains correct user name? If yes - can you login with this user in the same environment? For me it looks like one of the following happened: application settings changed (wrong user / wrong key), or user info changed in db (inactive?), or Membership provider changed

Comment: I have checked that and the user is valid. I can login as that user and run the task manually. I also tried different users and every single one of them failed with the same exception.

Comment: I think we need a bit more code to be able to review this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found a problem - application pool running with more than one worker processes (in my instance I had two worker processes). Once I set worker processes limit to one everything started to work again.

Comment: You break my mind, I don't see how it can be connected - do you feel it as an EPiServer issue?

Comment: Tell me about breaking the mind :) I felt like this for the last seven days. I believe that Episerver 6 does not work well with multiple worker processes. I suspect that the request is made to one worker process and completed by another sending back a blank user name which results in no roles and failed CurrentPrincipal. But this is only my theory.